# incompatible type for argument while using (matrix* mtx)

Tags: c, function, matrix

IDK know what is wrong but I get the error: main.c|45|error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'symmetric'(in printf)
If you can fix it please copy the fixed code, thank you!!
i think the mistakes are in the int main()

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct
{
    int n;
    int m;
    int** mat;
} matrix;

int symmetric(matrix* mtx)
{
    int i, j;

    if (mtx->n==mtx->m)
    {
        for ( i = 0; i <mtx->n; i++)
        {
            for ( j = 0; j < mtx->m; j++)
            {
                if( mtx->mat[i][j]!=mtx->mat[j][i] )
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
   matrix m = {
      .m = 3,
      .n = 3,
      .mat = {
        {1, 4, 4},
        {4, 1, 4},
        {4, 4, 10}
      }
    };

    printf("This matrix %s symmetric\n", symmetric(m)? "is" : "is not");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `symmetric(m)` -> `symmetric(&m)`

Comment: `struct matrix {int n; int m; int mat[3][3];};`

Comment: You can't initialize an `int **` with that notation.

Comment: worked but the problem is that this function should work with not only [3][3] it should work with any size n and m so ? @WilliamPursell

Comment: So you will need to use a different mechanism for initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created the matrix like:

```
matrix m = {
```

But your function takes a `matrix *`:

```
int symmetric(matrix* mtx)
```

So you need to pass a pointer to the matrix, not the actual matrix itself:

```
printf("This matrix %s symmetric\n", symmetric(&m)? "is" : "is not");
```

Note the `&m`, where `&` takes the address of the thing it's applied to, i.e. `m`.

Comment: that is a part of the mistakes there is one more with the **mat in the declarations

Comment: @joesouaid Agreed -- my answer addresses only the error that your question asks about. The problem William Pursell pointed out in comments regarding the creation of the matrix is another. As well, you code iterates over the entire matrix when in fact it only needs to consider the values on one side of the diagonal -- everything on the diagonal will always be symmetric, and if you test, say, the entry at (0,2), you don't need to also test the entry at (2,0). It's no big deal for a 3x3 matrix, but doing twice as much work as you need to can slow things down for a large matrix.